# How to implement Java Interface for Kafka (ConsumerRebalanceListener) in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka

There is a Java interface for Kafka:

```
public interface ConsumerRebalanceListener
```

How to implement that interface in Scala when trigger to use the rebalance listener is: `subscribing to a topic` ?

Thanks.

Comment: `extends ConsumerRebalanceListener`... Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
class ImplemetedClass extends ConsumerRebalanceListener{
  // Your implemenatation
}
```